# Как проверить и заменить данные из массивов?

Tags: php

Глупый вопрос, сразу говорю еще новичек во всем этом. стоит задача сверить два массива с данными:

```
    $arr1 = array(
    "1" => 'Пятницкое шоссе',
    "2" => 'Митино',
    "3" => 'Волоколамская',
    "4" => 'Охотный ряд');

   $arr2 = array(
   "4" => 'Охотный ряд',
   "5" => 'Лужники',
   "7" => 'Детский сад №3',
   "29" => 'Алтуфьево',
   "30" => 'Бибирево');
```

Задача следущая проверить их по названиям и если расходятся  в $arr1 заменить ключи.

делал так:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $id_m => $name_m) {
foreach ($arr2 as $rp_id => $rp_name_m) {
}
if ($rp_name_m != $name_m) {

    $id[] = $rp_id;

}
```

}

Но получилась (даже сам понял) какая то дичь((( код писать не прошу просто подскажите как делать? ну или что использовать. Заранее благодарю. Добра.

на выходе должно быть так

```
$arr1 = array( "1" => 'Пятницкое шоссе', "2" => 'Митино' ); 
$arr2 = array( "4" => 'Охотный ряд', "5" => 'Митино' );

$out = array( "1" => 'Пятницкое шоссе', "5" => 'Митино' );
```

Comment: пример выходного массива приведите, чтобы было понятно каким образом заменяются ключи

Comment: $arr1 = array(
    "1" => 'Пятницкое шоссе',
    "2" => 'Митино'
   );

   $arr2 = array(
   "4" => 'Охотный ряд',
   "5" => 'Митино'
  );$arr3 = array(
    "1" => 'Пятницкое шоссе',
    "5" => 'Митино'
   );

Comment: добавил в конец вопроса

Comment: так у вас весь массив расходится, что проверять если у всех значения разные. вы ради пример поставьте одинаковые значения хоть где-то дабы понять вопрос

Comment: а если в массиве 1 уже есть элемент с таким ID ?

Comment: Внутренний цикл слишком рано закрыл. Он бесполезен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $id_m => $name_m) {
  foreach ($arr2 as $rp_id => $rp_name_m) {
    if ($rp_name_m === $name_m) {
      unset($arr1[$id_m]);
      $arr[$rp_id] = $name_m;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо использовать [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-flip.php):

```
$arr1_inverted = array_flip($arr1);
$arr2_inverted = array_flip($arr2);

foreach ($arr_inverted2 as $key => $value) {
 if(array_key_exists($key, $arr1_inverted)) {
  $arr1_inverted[$key] = $value;
  }
 }

$final = array_flip($arr1_inverted);
```

Comment: он просто их соединил, а мне то немного другое нужно сверить данные по имени и если расходятся на имя которое проверяли вставить id из другого массива.

Comment: Не понятно почему в $out у вас кроме Митино ещё и Пятницкое, если вы. Олько сверяете по значениям и замещаете их ключи

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да вроде написано, что в первом контент остается, но при необходимости меняется ключ совпадающего